# SP2013: Disable text or number field once populated

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, list-form, conditional

I am looking for a jQuery script to conditionally disable two field types:

1. Disable a text field if it is not blank and
2. Disable a number field once it is non zero.

I see many posts on disabling People Pickers and Date fields, but not the above.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to disable the form fields on Edit form.

**For Single line of text field**: Consider column name is - Title

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input[title^='Title']").val()) {
        $("input[title^='Title']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    
        //$("input[title^='Title']").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    }
});
```

**For Number field**: Consider column name is - Content Amount

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input[title^='Content Amount']").val() != "0") {
        $("input[title^='Content Amount']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        
        //$("input[title^='Content Amount']").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ganesh, thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Have a great day and stay safe.

Comment: Hi Ganesh: Now I need to disable a date field once it is populated. Might you be able to help with this? Thank you!